# Python how to clip out the string I want?

Tags: python, string

A string from file like this:

```
aux_source_directory(detail LIB_SRC)
file(GLOB_RECURSE INC_ALL "./*.h")
autogen_ui(LIB_SRC)
add_library(qtdebugger_luadebugger ${LIB_SRC} ${INC_ALL})
target_link_libraries(qtdebugger_luadebugger PUBLIC Qt4::QtGui qtinfra debugger util infra opc)

if(test)
    add_subdirectory(unittest)
endif(test)
```

I want to clip out the words in `target_link_libraries()`. How can I do?

Comment: Read file. Loop through lines. Find line starting with `target_link_libraries`. Extract string between `(` and `)`.  --- Which part do you need help with? Also, have you attempted anything? Please share your code.

Comment: What if it contains several lines of target_link_libraries function. Still read it every line may not wok. I think it is better to read all the file text as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way which seems worked:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- 

import re

file_object = open("C:\Users/vlyu/Perforce/vlyu_GUI/qtgui/debugger/luadebugger/CmakeLists.txt", "r")
try:
 fileText = file_object.read()
 if fileText.find("target_link_libraries") != -1:
  index1 = fileText.index('target_link_libraries(')
  index2 = fileText.index(')', index1)
  print index1 
  print index2
  t1 = fileText[index1:index2+1]
  print t1
finally:
 file_object.close()
```